# VS Code - Custom syntax highlighting highlights only the first of a group of number / keywords

Tags: visual-studio-code, syntax-highlighting, vscode-extensions

I am currently trying to make a syntax highlighter extension in Visual Studio Code for a programming language that I am creating.

The syntax highlighter should highlight all of the keywords, but currently, I can't get it to highlight more than one per line, as in the image below (where all words should be highlighted).

[image]

The same happens with numbers:

[image]

This is my `<language name>.tmLanguage.json`:

```js
{
    "$schema": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/martinring/tmlanguage/master/tmlanguage.json",
    "name": "Language Name",
    "patterns": [
        {
            "include": "#control_keywords"
        },
        {
            "include": "#declaration_keywords"
        },
        {
            "include": "#double_quoted_strings"
        },
        {
            "include": "#single_quoted_strings"
        },
        {
            "include": "#hexadecimal_numbers"
        },
        {
            "include": "#octal_numbers"
        },
        {
            "include": "#binary_numbers"
        },
        {
            "include": "#decimal_numbers"
        },
        {
            "include": "#line_comments"
        },
        {
            "include": "#block_comments"
        }
    ],
    "repository": {
        "control_keywords": {
            "name": "keyword.control.language_name",
            "match": "\\b(if|while|for|return|continue|break|else)\\b"
        },
        "declaration_keywords": {
            "name": "keyword.declaration.language_name",
            "match": "\\b(fn|let|const)\\b"
        },
        "double_quoted_strings": {
            "name": "string.quoted.double.language_name",
            "begin": "\"",
            "end": "\"",
            "patterns": [
                {
                    "name": "constant.character.escape.language_name",
                    "match": "\\\\(\\\\|'|\"|n)"
                }
            ]
        },
        "single_quoted_strings": {
            "name": "string.quoted.single.language_name",
            "begin": "'",
            "end": "'",
            "patterns": [
                {
                    "name": "constant.character.escape.language_name",
                    "match": "\\\\(\\\\|'|\"|n)"
                }
            ]
        },
        "hexadecimal_numbers": {
            "name": "constant.numeric.hexadecimal",
            "match": "\\b0x[0123456789ABCDEFabcdef]*(\\.[0123456789ABCDEFabcdef]*)?\\b"
        },
        "octal_numbers": {
            "name": "constant.numeric.octal",
            "match": "\\b0o[01234567]*(\\.[01234567]*)?\\b"
        },
        "binary_numbers": {
            "name": "constant.numeric.octal",
            "match": "\\b0b[01]*(\\.[01]*)?\\b"
        },
        "decimal_numbers": {
            "name": "constant.numeric.decimal",
            "match": "\\b[0123456789]*(\\.[0123456789]*)?\\b"
        },
        "line_comments": {
            "name": "comment.line.double-slash",
            "match": "//[^\\n]*\n"
        },
        "block_comments": {
            "name": "comment.block",
            "begin": "/\\*",
            "end": "\\*/",
            "patterns": [
                {
                    "include": "#block_comments"
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    "scopeName": "source.language_name"
}
```

Comment: what is the need of the braces `()` in `([01234567])*`, I don't see entries for `break continue else`

Comment: @rioV8 I removed the unnecessary parentheses and added the missing keywords, but it still doesn't work